# Git: отказ слияния несвязанных историй изменений. Как исправить?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Создал удаленный репозитарий кода на bitbucket. Потом по [этой инструкции](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-unversioned-code-to-a-repository-877177133.html)
добавляю локальный репозиторий на bitbucket:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit of full repository'
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/perl.git
$ git push -u origin --all
```

Здесь появляется такое сообщение:

> To bitbucket.org:username/perl.git
>    ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
>   error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «git@bitbucket.org:username/perl.git»
>   подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как внешний репозиторий содержит
>   подсказка: изменения, которых у вас нет в вашем локальном репозитории.
>   подсказка: Обычно, это связанно с тем, что кто-то уже отправил изменения в 
>   подсказка: то же место. Перед повторной отправкой ваших изменений, вам нужно
>   подсказка: забрать и слить изменения из внешнего репозитория себе
>   подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …»).
>   подсказка: Для дополнительной информации, смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
>   подсказка: в «git push --help».

Ладно. Команда git pull origin master пишет следующее:

> warning: не общих коммитов
>   remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
>   remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   Распаковка объектов: 100% (3/3), готово.
>   Из bitbucket.org:username/perl
>    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
>    * [новая ветка]     master     -> origin/master
>   fatal: отказ слияния несвязанных историй изменений

Я пользовался раньше и Git, и Bitbucket, но такие проблемы у меня впервые. Вообще не понимаю, что за ерунда такая.

Comment: выполните `git fetch; git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all;`, добавьте вывод этой команды в вопрос ([edit]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В удаленном репозитории уже есть коммиты. тут есть несколько вариантов, как решить этот вопрос

1. Коммиты в удаленном репозитории нужны: `git pull`, после мержа -
   `git push`
2. Коммиты в удаленном репозитории НЕ нужны (например там
   добавлен пустой readme): `git push --force`. НЕ рекомендую делать
   такое, если история коммитов уже есть.

Comment: Коммиты в удаленном репозитории действительно были не нужны. Так что просто удалил тот удаленный и создал новый. С новым все работает. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ваш ответ вводит пользователей в заблуждение. Ответ от @alexglue **реально полезен**.

Answer (score 28):

Зря пометили как верный ответ от @dekanszn

Он скорее ломает чем чинит:
git pull попросту нельзя сделать ввиду ошибки, описанной в вопросе.
А удалять изменения не каждый захочет.

**Решается так:**

1. `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`
2. Затем решаем конфликты,
3. Затем commit & push

Comment: **Это верный ответ!** Ответ от @dekanszn абсолютно **неверен**.